# pgfplot marks with blurry outline

Tags: pgfplots

Is it possible for pgfplot to make a scatter plot with blurry outline as shown in the following figure? `\addplot [draw=white, fill=red]` can make a white outline and red inner cycle. But there is no blurry red outline.

[image: Red marks and blue marks]

Comment: Welcome. // "Needs more detail" often means: "we'd like to see your attempt as code." ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scatter/classes={
        a={mark=*,draw=white,fill=red,mark size=1.5}, % Solid red fill with white outline
        b={mark=*,draw=red,fill=red,opacity=0.1,mark size=2} % red mark for the glow
    },
]
\addplot[scatter,only marks,
    scatter src=explicit symbolic
] table[meta=label] {
x y label
1 1 b
1 1 a
2 2 b
2 2 a
3 3 b
3 3 a
4 4 b
4 4 a
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In pgfplots, the "mark size" parameter adjusts the size of plot marks.
The "opacity" parameter controls their transparency.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I need

Answer (score 1):

You can create your custom plot marks:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfdeclareplotmark{* glow}{
    \foreach \s in {0,...,5} {
        \fill[opacity=0.05, draw=none] (0,0) 
            circle[radius={2.85pt-\s*0.1pt}];
    }
    \fill[draw=white, line width=0.5pt] (0,0) 
        circle[radius=2pt];
}

\pgfdeclareplotmark{triangle glow}{
    \foreach \s in {0,...,5} {
        \fill[opacity=0.05, draw=none] (90:{3.9pt-\s*0.15pt}) 
            -- (210:{3.9pt-\s*0.15pt}) 
            -- (330:{3.9pt-\s*0.15pt}) -- cycle;
    }
    \fill[draw=white, line width=0.5pt] (90:2.5pt) 
        -- (210:2.5pt) -- (330:2.5pt) -- cycle;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=3cm, height=3cm, 
        xmin=0, xmax=1, 
        ymin=0, ymax=1,
        xtick={0,1},
        ytick={0,1}
    ]
    
     \addplot[mark=* glow, fill=red] coordinates {(0.2,0.2)};
     \addplot[mark=triangle glow, fill=blue] coordinates {(0.8,0.8)};
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This also works!